# How to disable vertical scroll of EditText?

Tags: java, android, scroll, android-edittext, vertical-scrolling

I create EditText programmatically.

Following is my code:

```
mEditText = new EditText(mMainActivity);
mEditText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
mEditText.setTextSize(8);
mEditText.setSingleLine();
mEditText.setMaxLines(1);
mEditText.setLines(1);
mEditText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

What I set above seems completely useless...Please help me.

Comment: Why did not use xml?

Comment: Have you did setup for with and height?

Answer (score 2):

You can try `setMovementMethod()` It will disable the `EditText` text scrolling. But you have to manage text size.

```
eText.setMovementMethod(null);
```

Hope it will help you...

Answer (score 1):

Set below properties:

```
mEditText.setSingleLine(true);
mEditText.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

What input type do you want?

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_**);
```

if email/phone you do not even need the

```
editText.setLines(1);
editText.setMaxLines(1);
```

Also note your method

```
editText.setSingleLine(false);
```

May be changing the values on your maxLines and Lines methods.